# Lex program count numbers of integer, the numbers of double, numbers of hexadecimal, Number of String

Tags: unix, count, numbers, integer, lex

I try to write a Lex program that counts the numbers of integer, the numbers of double, numbers of hexadecimal, Number of String and also count numbers of function headers from this file:
[image]

I write this code :

[image]

[image]

but I don't know why it gives me a wrong result and also prints all contents of the file

My output:

[image]

Expected output :
[image]

can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To make things easier, please copy paste your code and your output instead of linking images.

Comment: My suggestion is "don't use macros" (aka definitions). But if you're going to use them, the syntax for a macro expansion is `{hex}`, not `[hex]` nor `{ hex }`. All of the possible pattern syntaxes are described in detail [in the manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html). It's not very long because there are only a few valid syntaxes. In particular, if you want to use names to describe sets like "hexadecimal digits" or "alphanumeric characters", use the built-in names: `[[:xdigit:]]`, `[[:alnum:]]`, etc.